# Draw on screen with CoreGraphics when hit NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw something simple on screen when `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` gets called but nothings happen.
Is there any other way to catch an exception and quickly draw something on screen?

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&exceptionHandler);

void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 450.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(310.0, 450.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(310.0, 10.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

    [APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW.rootViewController.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: are you sure that execution is entering your handler? does it work if the exception occurs on the main thread?

Comment: oh and are you *positive* that `APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW.rootViewController.view.layer` is not nil?

Comment: "..The uncaught exception handler always causes the program to exit.." So adding a shape to the screen seems to make no sense. you can read the rest here [Apple Docs UncaughtExceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Concepts/UncaughtExceptions.html). Maybe its possible to save the shape to an image on the filesystem.

Comment: yeah seems to always cause an exit. could maybe get around it by doing what you are trying to do in its own runloop tho.

Comment: I'm sure execution entering the handler as I did some logging and i'm sure 'APP_DELEGATE_WINDOW.rootViewController.view.layer' is not nil as i'm using it in different parts in my app.

Comment: Maybe there is a different way to add a shape or draw something on screen when exception occur? Something like 'Ubertesters SDK' doing (when exception hit, they draw nice alert on screen).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` is a good place to draw stuff on the screen.

> Sets the top-level error-handling function where you can perform
>   last-minute logging before the program terminates.

Most crash reporters carefully log the trace and try not to "touch" anything besides.

If you really want to draw something (what?) you should maybe catch a particular exception first. Just not any uncaught exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think **Rivera** is right, about `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`. And maybe you need to write: `[path fill];`

P.S : I'm sorry that i write here, comments disabled, small reputation...

Answer (score 1):

Like Rivera said, you won't be able to rescue the application at this stage, but if you really needed to draw something here, you could probably launch another process (which you would have to design) just to show this image.